# Ant conditions - which comes first 'if' or 'unless'

Tags: ant, conditional-statements, target

**Question**

If an ant target uses both *if* and *unless*, which is evaluated first?

**Example**

What comes first, the chicken or the egg? . . .

```
<target name="prepare" if="chicken" unless="egg" >
    <echo>Dinner time. Chicken is served!</echo>
</target>
```

Would ant evaluate the chicken property first?  Or the egg property?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It isn't really a question of evaluation, since the properties either are or are not set before the target gets called.

EDIT: I looked at the 1.8.1 source and the logic is as follows:

```
if (!testIfAllows()) {
    project.log(this, "Skipped because property '" + project.replaceProperties(ifCondition)
            + "' not set.", Project.MSG_VERBOSE);
    return;
}
if (!testUnlessAllows()) {
    project.log(this, "Skipped because property '"
            + project.replaceProperties(unlessCondition) + "' set.", Project.MSG_VERBOSE);
    return;
}
```

So the `unless` won't matter unless the `if` passes. But keep in mind, these don't have anything to do with evaluating properties. It just looks them up to see if they are set.

Comment: The relevant class is [org.apache.tools.ant.Target](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/tags/ANT_181/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/Target.java)