# Ant if and unless: Is it AND or OR condition?

Tags: if-statement, ant, conditional-statements, target

I have something like this:

```
<target name="X" if="A" unless="B">...</target>
```

Now I need to understand how is this condition evaluated.
Is it:

```
if (A AND NOT B)
```

Or is it:

```
if (A OR NOT B)
```

Thanks!

Comment: A **AND** NOT B.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084014/ant-conditions-which-comes-first-if-or-unless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accept the comment of martin clayton as an answer:

A AND NOT B. See [execute Ant task if TWO conditions are met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097555/execute-ant-task-if-two-conditions-are-met)